# How to get a content after making POST to create new issue in Gitlab API

Tags: c#, rest, gitlab, dotnet-httpclient

In Gitlab API You can post new issue using this:

POST https://localhost/api/v4/projects/2779/issues?title=NewIssue

So in my cmd app I'm using something like this:

```
using (var httpClient = new HttpClient()) // post issue
{
    using (var request = new HttpRequestMessage(new HttpMethod("POST"), issue_path + issue_title))
    {
        request.Headers.TryAddWithoutValidation("PRIVATE-TOKEN", "XxXx_xZx4x6xx74xxxXx");
        var response3 = await httpClient.SendAsync(request);
    }
}
```

To POST new ISSUE and I don't know how to get IID of this new issue.
In RESTer I get response and a content of this new issue but I don't know how to get content after this POST request without another GET.

Comment: isn't your IID returned in the Content property of your response3? So you can do a `var iid = await response3.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();` ?

Comment: yep... i don't know why it isn't work for me before

Answer (score 0):

Ok i found an answer!!!

```
 {
   using (var request = new HttpRequestMessage(new HttpMethod("POST"), issue_path + issue_title))
  {
    request.Headers.TryAddWithoutValidation("PRIVATE-TOKEN", "XxXX_xZx4x6xx74XXxXx");
    var response3 = await httpClient.SendAsync(request);
    var content3 = await response3.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
    Issue new_issue = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Issue>(content3);
    int new_issue_iid = new_issue.iid; 

   }
}
```